# Re-using templates without editing

Tags: civimail

I would like to use a newsletter template from a different chapter. I am afraid if I edit the template it will change their settings they have in place. I simply just want to copy what they have and edit the text I will need for the Atlanta newsletter.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're asking to do is possible, but the answer depends on your version of CiviCRM.  That's why it's good to put your CiviCRM version into your question when asking!  You can find it at the bottom of every page.  I'll try to give some answers below.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The way I'm describing below isn't the easiest method, but it should work in all versions of CiviCRM.

- Go to **Mailings menu » Message Templates**.
- Press "Edit" next to the template you'd like to copy.
- In the editor, you should see a "Source" button.  It may look different depending on your version of CiviCRM, but the most common version looks like this:
  [image]
- You'll see the raw HTML, which looks like gibberish.  You'll want to do a "Select All" and "Copy" (Ctrl-A, then Ctrl-C on Windows).
- Press "Cancel" to go back to the message templates selection screen.
- Press "Add Message Template" to start a new template
- On the new (blank) template, press the "Source" button.
- Paste in the raw HTML from the origin template.
- Press "Source" again, and it should look like the original - but now you're in a copy of the original template!  Save this one with its own name and edit it however you like.

Comment: ideally there would be a way of duplicating like reports, but this works!