# Add Custom CSS to Civi Email

Tags: civimail, email, message-templates

How can i add some custom css to a message template? I want to add it to the header. Is there a file I can edit?

Answer (score 2):

I just saw, all I need to do is click on the source button in the message editor and paste my code in there as described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18485/re-using-templates-without-editing)